# How to get out coefficient of term in series?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

Suppose I have a function $f(s,t) = [(1-t^2)(1-s^2t^2)]^{-1/2}$.

Is there a way to get the general coefficient in this power series of the form $s^{2k} t^{2n}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Artes shows, `Series` can produce selected coefficients.  We can go further: `FindSequenceFunction` finds closed forms for lists.  We have to commit some small sins:

- We assert that odd coefficients are 0 with opportune `[[;; ;;2]]`s, not too bad
- We assert that there are closed forms for each coefficient list $(a_n(k)s^{2k}t^{2n})_n$, and
- The general coefficient $a(n,k)=a_n(k)$ will admit an obvious closed form.

So we try

```
FindSequenceFunction@#[[;; ;;2]]&/@CoefficientList[Series[
  1/Sqrt[(1-t^2)(1-s^2t^2)],{s,0,20},{t,0,20}
],{s,t}][[;; ;;2]]
```

which yields

```
{Pochhammer[1/2,#1-1]/Pochhammer[1,#1-1]&,
 Pochhammer[1/2,#1-2]/(2Pochhammer[1,#1-2])&,
 3Pochhammer[1/2,#1-3]/(8Pochhammer[1,#1-3])&,...}
```

where there are a few garbage elements towards the end of the list.  This is promising.  Type

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1,1/2,3/8,5/16,35/128,63/256}]
```

to obtain `Pochhammer[1/2,#1-1]/Pochhammer[1,#1-1]&`.  It would seem

```
Sum[Pochhammer[1/2,i-n]/Pochhammer[1,i-n]Pochhammer[1/2,n-1]/Pochhammer[1,n-1]
  s^(2(n-1))t^(2(i-1)),{n,1,\[Infinity]},{i,1,\[Infinity]}]
```

is the series expansion we are looking for.  Obviously this method is highly manual.  Still, Mathematica was of assistance.

Expanding some definitions and applying some identities, we obtain
$$f(s,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\prod_{j=1}^i\left(j-n-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(1+i-n)}s^{2n}t^{2i}.$$
I think those two $\Gamma$'s can be eliminated, but I'm not very good at complex analysis.  I don't know where this is convergent.

Here's a coinciding plot of the two functions

```
g[s_,t_]=Sum[
  ((-1)^n Product[j-n-1/2,{j,i}])/(Gamma[n+1]Gamma[1+i-n])s^(2n)t^(2i),{n,0,10},{i,0,10}];
Plot3D[{g[s,t],1/Sqrt[(1-t^2)(1-s^2t^2)]},{s,-1,1},{t,-1,1}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that one deals with series expansion around $(s,t)=(0,0)$ we can define

```
cf[k_, n_] := 
  Series[1/Sqrt[(1 - t^2) (1 - s^2 t^2)], {s, 0, 2 k}, {t, 0, 2 n}] // 
  Normal // Coefficient[#, s^(2 k) t^(2 n)] &
```

We have defined `cf` to get only even coefficients `(2k,2n)`, since the others do vanish.

```
Table[cf[k, n], {k, 6}, {n, 6}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

One can get the same with Array as well

```
Array[ cf, {6, 6}] == Table[ cf[k, n], {k, 6}, {n, 6}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This appraoch would be satisfactory for small `{n, k}`. For bigger ones there is `SeriesCoefficient` (as another answer recalled).

```
sf[k_, n_]:= SeriesCoefficient[ 1/Sqrt[(1 - t^2) (1 - s^2 t^2)], {s, 0, 2k}, {t, 0, 2n}]

Array[ cf, {6, 6}] == Array[ sf, {6, 6}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

And `sf` is much better than `cf`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[sf[350, 400];]
```

> ```
> {0.0015182, Null}
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming[cf[350, 400];]
```

> ```
> {10.2873, Null}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this would be to simply use `SeriesCoefficient`, e.g.

```
SeriesCoefficient[1/Sqrt[1 + t^2], {t, 0, n}]
```

produces the general form

```
(I^n (1/2 (-1 + n))!)/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] (n/2)!)
```

for `Mod[n, 2] == 0 && n >= 0`. However, it seems to have trouble with your particular function, so you may need to resort to guessing as @Adam has shown...